# Grace Design Spacebar SB-30

Tags: omni, stereo, field-recording

I'd liked to get input on the Grace Design Spacebar SB-30 for potential use in a compact spaced omni nature recording rig? Is 30cm too close together for a good spaced image? Can you angle the omni's outward? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find 30cm spaced omnis will provide too narrow an image for nature recording. Placing the omnis at an angle will do very little (if anything) to widen the image, since by very nature, omnis aren't directional. The larger 66cm spacebar would work better for this application, but even then, you're probably better off mounting the mics on separate stands for greater control of the stereo width. The only way to work with Omnis in a more compact setup would be to use a Jecklin Disc.

Comment: Thanks @Justin, forgive the ignorance but how do cardioids provide a wide image in an ORTF set up but omnis at the same angle don't? Feel free to just link me if there are websites out there with this info. Thanks!

Comment: The simple answer: directionality of the pickup pattern. The complicated answer, read this:

http://www.reddingaudio.com/downloads/Rycote%20Technical/The%20Stereophonic%20Zoom.pdf

DPA microphones also has a lot of great info on their website in the "microphone university" section.

Comment: Great link Justin, thanks. On my "to read thoroughly" list.